# How to get object value out of array?

Tags: typescript

so i have made a piece of code with typescript where it stores information into an array so that it can be used later but now im trying to get the value out of the array but i cant seem to find how.

this is the code where i declare the array

```
            const eventId: any[] | undefined = await runQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM event WHERE `description` = (?)",
                [name]
            );
```

this is the array i get

```
0
: 
{eventId: 29, description: 'Omer', dateCreated: '2023-12-14T13:09:07.000Z'}
```

ive tried diffrent versions of

```
    const filteredData = eventArray.filter(any.eventId);
```

but i still cant find a way

Comment: Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing, along with a clear description of the precise result you're expecting to see.  Right now it's not obvious what the problem is or how to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the content of a single array element?

To do this, you can use the following:

```
arrayName[indexNumber];
```